# Query large data in MongoDB using aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, mongodb-atlas

We're facing an issue, we have an *M2 cluster* in MongoDB Atlas. We have around **7000 documents** in collection `User` and around **22000 documents** in collection `Order`.

When we fire the below query, we don't get any result, response or error in return even if we wait for a long time.

So how to handle this situation and there are only 7000 users but what if we have millions of users and orders in our database.

```
 User.aggregate([
 {$match: query},
 {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'orders',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: '_userId',
      as: 'userorders'
    }
  }]);
```

Comment: What is `query` and what happens if you just do the `$match` without a lookup?   Does it still run forever?

Comment: Yes, we get data without lookup. The query is some conditions that we use to filter out data. For Example, `{$match: {balance: {$gt: 10}}}`

Comment: Are you sure that collection `Orders` are using key `_userId`, not `userId`?

Comment: We're sure that the query is right. In fact, we're getting data if we dump same data in our local machine and query on it.

Comment: @Viral Raval, you can add `{$limit: 10}` between `$match` and `$lookup`, if we get data or response, the problem maybe from Atlas

Comment: M2 is a very small instance.  I believe that level is shared on a single machine with other users, so the database process is limited to 2 GB of RAM, and due to sharing it may only get a partial CPU.  So an M2 node has somewhat less computing power than on old iphone, aside from the explicit [limitations](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/#free-shared-tier-cluster-limitations).  If it works on your local machine, see what happens with an Atlas size with the same resources.